# How to synchronize multiple audio files on iOS?

Tags: ios, audio

I like to synchronize (one-shot) audio effects with the beat of (looping) background music on iOS.

How do I approach that task?

Edit: So, to give more details, say the background music loops over 4 bars. I want to be able to start the playback of another audio file (of an audio effect) on the next 8th (or 16th or 4th...) note.

Comment: Simple... play the sound at the right time.  I don't know what else you expect in an answer, as you've provided no details what-so-ever as to the method you are using to play audio, and what exactly your question is.

Comment: Well, actually that's the question - what method should I use? Obviously, it needs to be precise enough to know when to start the sound effect - but how? (E.g. can I query where the current playback-position in the music-loop is? How do I know when playback has started **exactly**? etc.)

Comment: How accurate does it need to be?  I'm not familiar with the iOS stack, but I suspect if you need anything close to sample-accurate, you'll need to mix the audio yourself before sending it to the buffer for playback.  For music purposes, anything beyond a few milliseconds off becomes very noticeable, so I bet mixing ahead of the time is the way to go.  This also gives you more control, as far as levels and what not go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. Put them on the same timeline (e.g. audio playback callback), and use the input tempo to determine the metric intervals in samples (or ticks, if using MIDI events).

**Update**

```
double SamplesPerBeat(const double audioSampleRate,
                      const double beatsPerMinute) {
  assert(8000.0 <= audioSampleRate && 192000.0 >= audioSampleRate);
  assert(20.0 <= beatsPerMinute && 500.0 >= beatsPerMinute);
  return audioSampleRate / beatsPerMinute;
}

uint32_t StartPosition(const double audioSampleRate,
                       const double beatsPerMinute,
                       const uint32_t beatNumber) {
  const double samplesPerBeat = SamplesPerBeat(audioSampleRate, beatNumber);
  return (uint32_t)floor(samplesPerBeat * beatNumber);
}
```

Comment: Justin, thanks - do you have some code or link to get me started? Say I know the tempo, how do I determine the sample position of the first  loop, and start the second sound in n samples from now?